# Addition and Division on Wix using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, division, addition, velo

I am new to this and have no coding experience so I need some help. I need javascript coding that can add multiple numbers together and then divide the sum by another number. If anyone knows how to input this into wix, that would also be super helpful.

Comment: Suppose your `multiple numbers` are in an array-variable called `arrNum` and your divisor is in a variable called `numDiv`, then: `arrNum.reduce((t, i) => (t + i))/numDiv` should give the desired result. Please try it & share your feedback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.